# Spring MVC Absolute path to relative path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am trying to define a relative path instead of an absolute path with spring mvc. anyone have any idea how to do it?

```
private static final String FILE_PATH = "/Users/andyhe/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.3.RELEASE/gti660/Equipe5/src/iTunesClone - Lab 2/iTunesClone/WebContent/resources/download/json/recherche.json";

private File getFileP() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
    if (!file.exists()){
        throw new FileNotFoundException("file with path: " + FILE_PATH + " was not found.");
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Spring.
Create folder `src/main/resources` and keep your files there.
Then find them by:

```
URL resource = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("recherche.json")
File file = new File(resource.getFile());
```

continue from there..